# Does MKL provide any advantage to R besides basic algebra?

Tags: r, intel-mkl

When installing R you can choose between plain R and other distributions including the MKL libraries such as Microsoft R.
There are other distributions such Oracle R or you can compile R yourelf with other libraries such as BLAS.

MKL is supposed to increase the speed of matrix algebraic operations like Matrix Multiplication, Cholesky Factorization, Singular Value Decomposition or Principal Components Analysis.

Does it offer any other advantages not related with matrix algebra?

Would I benefit from MKL if I'm not explicitly using any of these operations?
For example if I'm selecting rows and computing averages by group?
Does R use them internally even if the user doesn't notice it?
For example if I'm using the package lme4 does it use MKL internally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using Intel® MKL with R does offer many other advantages apart from matrix algebra. Guess you would have referred [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-with-r) link on how to use mkl with R.

You might notice a significant difference while running heavy jobs.

Intel® MKL's features include:[[Source]](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl)

1. Features highly optimized, threaded, and vectorized math functions that maximize performance on each processor family
2. Uses industry-standard C and Fortran APIs for compatibility with popular BLAS, LAPACK, and FFTW functions—no code changes required
3. Dispatches optimized code for each processor automatically without the need to branch code

Comment: Can you provide any example of such functions besides matrix functions and FFT?

Comment: Yeah. There are many other functions such as  Intel® Math Kernel Library for Deep Neural Networks (Intel® MLK-DNN), Vector Statistics & Data Fitting,etc.                                                                                                                  Refer to the links below:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/features/deep-neural-networks
https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/features/statistics
https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/features/vector-math-misc-solvers

Comment: But is there an R API for all of those functions though? E.g. for those Intel MKL Deep Neural Networks?